# Javascript charting library

Tags: library, javascript, charts

I am looking for a JavaScript charting library. My requirements are:

- 2D line charts and bar charts
- Zoom on X-axis with the possibility to synchronize zooming of several charts
- Multiple lines on the same chart with same X-axis
- Export to base64 data string (png)
- A way to add milestones on X-axis with icons
- Popup or popover with custom content and HTML links inside.
- Free, open-source
- No huge dataset, probably SVG based is great.
- CSS support
- I18N support
- Usable with Angular

For the moment, I am considering plotlyjs and HighCharts. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: HighCharts is excellent but not free-of-cost. Is free-of-cost a requirement (as you listed) or not?

Comment: Ideally yes. However, HighCharts is interesting because of affordable High-five License for pre-revenue or pre-financing startups which is applicable to us.

Comment: HighCharts is nearly good but the way tooltips are implemented make it unfriendly to click on the links when the dataset is dense :-(

Comment: http://visjs.org/ may be worth a look

Answer (score 4):

[Syncfusion EJ2 Chart for Angular](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/chart) supports most of the requirements.

- 2D line charts and bar charts

  Supports different types of line series and bar series.
  [Demo](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/angular/demos/#/material/chart/line)

  For more information on line series and bar series [refer](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/chart/chart-types.html)
- Zoom on X-axis with the possibility to synchronize zooming of several charts

  For more information on zooming [refer](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/chart/zooming.html)

  Demo [link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/angular/demos/#/material/chart/zooming)

  [image]
- Mulitple lines on the same chart with same X-axis

  Yes. We can have multi lines on the same chart with same X axis.

  Demo [link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/angular/demos/#/material/chart/symbols)
  [image]
- Export to base64 data string (png)

  Export to base64 Demo [Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f255ad?file=src%2Findex.html)

  And chart can also exported to other format. For more information on exporting follow the demo link.

  1. PNG
  2. SVG
  3. JPG
  4. PDF

  Demo [link](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/16.2.41/angular/demos/#/material/chart/export)

  For more information on export [refer](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/chart/chart-print.html)
- A way to add milestones on X-axis with icons

  Milestones can be achieved by using annotation feature:

  Demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7cat79?file=src/app/app.component.html)

  For more information on annotation [refer](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/chart/chart-annotations.html)

[image: Syncfusion Chart with milestones]

- Popup or popover with custom content and HTML links inside.

  On move hover, a popup will show the information about points, we can customize this popup with template to show the custom content.

  Demo [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zn1qsn?file=src/index.html)
  [image]
- Free, open-source

  Commercial product, free option available under [community license](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).
- No huge dataset, probably SVG based is great.

  Yes, our EJ2 chart component is SVG based.
- CSS support

  All the appearance can be customized by using  in-built API’s.
- I18N support

  Yes, EJ2 Chart control support I18N
- Usable with Angular

  Yes usable with Angular platform. All the above mentioned samples are in Angular.

Note : I work for Syncfusion.

Please let me know if you have any queries.